# MAMP or MySQL on macOS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

Yesterday I have installed MAMP on mac OS. Everything's perfect.

How I can get my mysql version? In terminal write something like this: mysql -v ? ( This doesnt work).

And there phpmyadmin, if i create database , tables so I can use them in ruby on rails projects?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `mysql` in your terminal, you'll be greeted with a welcome message that includes the version.

From the terminal, you can also do:

```
mysql --version
```

And from within mysql:

```
select version();
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://localhost:8888/MAMP to see details about your MAMP installation and http://localhost:8888/MAMP/phpmyadmin.php for the MAMP phpMyAdmin interface.

There you'll also see the configuration details how to connect to the database (usable in Ruby, too).

On the command line, you'll need to use the right path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -V
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";